# Are temporaries bound to const references considered const objects?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, temporary-objects

Consider this piece of code:

```
struct X
{
    int a;
};

X getX();

void modify(const X& x)
{
    const_cast<X&>(x).a++;
}

int foo()
{
    X x0 = getX();
    const X x1 = getX();
    const X& x2 = getX();

    // Legal!
    modify(x0);

    // Illegal!
    //modify(x1);

    // Legal?
    modify(x2);

    return x0.a + x1.a + x2.a;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/72pLzd

`modify` casts away the constness of its reference argument. This is legal as long as the referenced object is not itself `const` (which is why the constness of const references rarely confers optimization benefits).

I would like to understand the case of a temporary bound to a const ref. Is such an object always `const`, always non-`const`, or does it depend on where the temporary came from/how it was constructed (i.e. would it matter if `getX` returned a `const X`)?

Comment: Would be nice to see the implementation of `getX`.

Comment: @sp2danny: "Considering you are allowed to bind temporaries to non-const reference" - U wot?

Comment: @Bathsheba Would the implementation matter? NRVO is just an optimization, it shouldn't affect whether `x2` is considered a `const` object or not?

Comment: @Bathsheba There's definitely no lifetime problem in the example.

Comment: @Bathsheba No, the dupe is good (and I myself accepted it as dupe target, hence Community). I just didn't find it myself.